# Android SharedPreferences' embroiled casting

Tags: android, casting

I am working right now with Android's `SharedPreferences`.

I have set some preference binded to `EditTextPreference` - so content is `String` type and we access it with:

```
String defaultValue = "1337";
String value = preferences.getString("key", defaultValue);
```

But what about we want to work with `int` value ?

```
int defaultValue = 1337;
int value = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("key", String.valueOf(defaultValue)));
```

Is there a better way ? Can I somehow set `EditTextPreference` to be `int` typed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow set EditTextPreference to be int typed ?

No, sorry. You can create your own custom subclass of `DialogPreference`, perhaps even a subclass of `EditTextPreference` (not sure how flexible that is), that saves values as an integer value in the `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't want to edit a numeric value as text, except as a secondary power-user method.  There are so many ways you might want to constrain the value (e.g., min/max, or enumerated values) that it makes sense to use a widget that returns a result that is correct by construction.  Both from the programming perspective and UX.